# Hide selected item & show another item instead from a list of items in jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to switch a `button` with a `textbox` from a list of table rows. I'm using `asp.net mvc 4` & `jquery 1.9.1`. The problem is the button I click gets hidden but textbox are appearing in all of the rows. My codes are below,

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.btnDue').click(function () {
            $(this).hide();
            $('.txtDue').show();
        });
    });
</script>
<body>
    @foreach(var item in Model.DueList)
    {
        <tr><td><button class="btnDue">Set Due</button>@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.due, new { @class = "txtDue", hidden = "hidden" })</td></tr>
    }
</body>
```

How can I show only the textbox where I clicked the button? Need this help badly. Tnx.

Comment: it might be useful to use Id attribute or possibly classes to make this easier for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`.next` function](https://api.jquery.com/next/) to select the following sibling which have the `txtDue`class :

```
$('.btnDue').click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).next('.txtDue').show();
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g9radyrg/1/)

Comment: There is a lot of [traversing functions in jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/) And some of them avec very usefull :)

Answer (score 1):

$('.txtDue') will apply to all the inputs that have the txtDue class. To reference the input that is beside the button you have clicked, try:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.btnDue').click(function () {
            $(this).hide();
            $(this).siblings('.txtDue').show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('.txtDue').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('.txtDue')` refers to all divs with the class 'txtDue', and this is why it is showing all of them when you click any button.

I don't know how many text boxes we are talking about, but if it's not too many then you may want to give them id's, so you may reference them individually.

Comment: No, I cannot use id because from time to time datas will increase so the rows will increase. I need a method which will work even if the rows are increased. Thanks.

Comment: I see. I think the answers referring to 'next' or 'closest' will be your best bet then.